# Trouble upgrading nodejs to version 0.6.3-1 in ArchLinux

Tags: arch-linux, node.js

I'm trying to upgrading nodejs to version 0.6.3-1 in ArchLinux, but get a conflict during the "checking for file conflicts" step. It complains about a bunch of files in the npm directory:

```
nodejs: /usr/bin/npm exists in filesystem
nodejs: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/.gitmodules exists in filesystem
nodejs: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/AUTHORS exists in filesystem
nodejs: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/CHANGES exists in filesystem
nodejs: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/LICENSE exists in filesystem
...
```

I found out there have been some changes in that package regarding the inclusion of NPM but I don't see how to get the upgrade to work without wiping all my NPM packages. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tell pacman to just overwrite the conflicting files using `--force`.

```
pacman -S --force nodejs
```

See [*Upgrade options*](http://www.archlinux.org/pacman/pacman.8.html#_upgrade_options_apply_to_em_s_em_and_em_u_em_a_id_uo_a) in [`pacman(8)`](http://www.archlinux.org/pacman/pacman.8.html).

---

**Note: Be very careful with the `--force` option. It breaks things more often than it fixes.**

Comment: I understand that `--force` can be used, but is there a safer way to do this easily?

Comment: @NicolasMcCurdy: Only by manually removing the conflicting files.